# Data table's features disable when using other scripts for bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

[Picture of head contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n5Lp.png)I'm developing a small web page and I'm using datatables, when I add some other js for Bootstrap modal, features of my datatable go missing and if I don't use these then my modal don't show on click.[Modal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmLqQ.png)

Here is my code of Modal which I'm unable to open:

```
<!--Modal Details-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="printThis">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">TEA BILL</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"> 
                <label style="color: black;">Name</label>
                <h5 style="color: black;">Mr. Akbar Ali</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label  style="color: black;">For the month of</label>
                <h5  style="color: black;">FEB 2018</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="myTableItems">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="color: black;">
                            <th scope="col">Item</th>
                            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                            <th scope="col">Amount</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="color: black;">
                            <th scope="row">Tea</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="color: black;">
                            <th scope="row">Coffee</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="color: black;">
                            <th scope="row">Biscuit</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="color: black;">
                            <th scope="row">Drinks</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="color: black;">
                            <th scope="row">Tea Break</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="color: black;">
                            <th scope="row">Misc</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label  style="color: black;">Total</label>
                  <h2  style="color: black;">0</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label  style="color: black;">Arrear</label>
                  <h2  style="color: black;">0</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label  style="color: black;">Grand Total</label>
                  <h2  style="color: black;">0</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                  <br><br><p style="color: black; font: 12px;"><strong>IC Offrs Tea Bar</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnPrint" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Print</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Modal works when I use particular script links but datatable features go missing

Comment: can you post the code here? not with the link.

Comment: no, not with the upload. i mean put the code here on this site.

Comment: please share your code here, don't share images,

Comment: I've shared my code, please check now.

Comment: Are there any JS errors appearing in the console? I ask this because the problem only occurs when adding the modal JS alongside the datatables JS.